# Identify Unique Sentences in SQL String with Repeat Sentences

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, split, varchar

I have a VARCHAR(MAX) string field in SQL that, in some instances, contains up to 100k char in LEN. Lets call it [Notes_Comments].

The contents of the field, [Notes_Comments], are notes and comments and in several instances have those notes and comments copied/pasted in multiple times. There is no delineation as to where the old and new parts start/end. Punctuation is also hit and miss.

I would like to figure out how to identify the unique sentences, or strings/substrings, within the [Notes_Comments] field to essentially get a pure, deduplicated, view of contents.

I built a SplitString function and was able to start parsing out 2,3 and 5 word phrases but it isn't really getting me to where I need to get for full sentences.

Example [Notes_Comments]:

I want to get this

---

10:46 AM Talked to blah about blah 11:46 AM They said they didn’t know what I meant 12:46 PM Built a SplitString function and parsed words into a table with a word index 1:46 PM Good progress to identify words but not full strings 2:46 PM Removing noise words 3:46 PM Removing known categories of words 4:46 PM Trying to figure out how to remove repeat parts of the one string field. Notes Some duplicate stuff. Now some new stuff has been added. Notes Added a little more. Must deduplicate portions of text that appear more than once. Notes One more section.

---

From this

---

10:46 AM Talked to blah about blah 11:46 AM They said they didn’t know what I meant 12:46 PM Built a SplitString function and parsed words into a table with a word index 1:46 PM Good progress to identify words but not full strings 2:46 PM Removing noise words 3:46 PM Removing known categories of words Notes Some duplicate stuff **10:46 AM Talked to blah about blah 11:46 AM They said they didn’t know what I meant 12:46 PM Built a SplitString function and parsed words into a table with a word index 1:46 PM Good progress to identify words but not full strings 2:46 PM Removing noise words 3:46 PM Removing known categories of words 4:46 PM Trying to figure out how to remove repeat parts of the one string field. Notes Some duplicate stuff. Now some new stuff has been added. Notes Added a little more. Must deduplicate portions of text that appear more than once.** 10:46 AM Talked to blah about blah 11:46 AM They said they didn’t know what I meant 12:46 PM Built a SplitString function and parsed words into a table with a word index 1:46 PM Good progress to identify words but not full strings 2:46 PM Removing noise words 3:46 PM Removing known categories of words 4:46 PM Trying to figure out how to remove repeat parts of the one string field. Notes Some duplicate stuff. Now some new stuff has been added. Notes Added a little more. Must deduplicate portions of text that appear more than once. **Notes One more section.**

---

Here is my SplitString function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString 
(
    @str NVARCHAR(max), 
    @separator CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
WITH tokens(p, a, b) AS (
    SELECT 
        CAST(1 AS bigint), 
        CAST(1 AS bigint), 
        CHARINDEX(@separator, @str)
    UNION all
    SELECT
        p + 1, 
        b + 1, 
        CHARINDEX(@separator, @str, b + 1)
    FROM tokens
    WHERE b > 0
)
SELECT
    p-1 ItemIndex,
    SUBSTRING(
        @str, 
        a, 
        CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN b-a ELSE LEN(@str) END) 
    AS word
FROM tokens
);

GO
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) This feels like a multi-level problem, with a wide range of possible answers. The deduping you describe would be complex in SQL, so if you're OK with surrounding logic in a PHP, Java, etc, mention that. Doing this on a ginormous varchar is about the most painful way possible, so also worth saying whether there's a rationale for keeping it that way, or whether you're open to other designs. Posting your SplitString code would help give pointers on where you could go from there. Finally, is this a one-off or regular operation, and what's your dataset size?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome.

I am open to surrounding it with whatever it takes.

In the end I will need to be able to query the data so I will need the end result to be in a format to either import or load back into the db.

The current dataset sits in SQL and it will be an operation that runs weekly against a couple thousand rows.

Answer (score 1):

To help going forward I would recommend taking that "Notes" column off of the table it is currently on, and making a new table of "EntityId", and "Note".  EntityId being that of the parent record you want to associate the note to.  In this way you have a one-to-many relationship between your entity and notes.

This will require quite a bit of work to change over, but maintaining it will be much easier and prevent similar issues to the one you are currently having.

For a purely sql approach I would change the table relationships first.  Perform your split, and insert each individual message into the new table.  After doing that you can write a separate procedure for identifying duplicates and perform deletes on all but one of those.

I should note that below is an application approach.

If you choose to update your table relationships, implement it first, then de-duping will become a two-step process, but relatively simple to implement.

For de-duping, you have to account for the fact that you said punctuation is hit or miss.

I would split on the :??AM and :??PM syntax of your timestamps.  You'll have to work out the syntax but that should help you identify where an entry begins and ends.  Split those into a list, Trim() each one as you add it, if you don't need the punctuation at all, do a replace on "." and "," and other punctuation characters you don't want as you add them to your collection as well.

Now you have two options, if you went with the table update, you could insert all of the values and then filter for duplicates after, in either sql or in code.

Or you can create a new list, do some looping and add only unique items to this new list.  If you kept your single column concat them into one string and update your db, or if you went with the one-to-many design perform an insert for each unique entry.

If you want to do less exact matching, build a hash for each substring.  Perhaps "timestamp" + " " + first X chars + last Y chars.  Then compare your hashes for equality, again keeping only one.  I recommend this pattern because it looks from your example that duplicate notes have duplicate timestamps.  If not try only first x and last y as a hash.

I highly recommend updating your table structure to save you similar headaches in the future.  The rest is a little bit of regex, and string splitting and comparison.  Also, experiment in debug with the hashing if you try to use it to make sure you don't cut out too much before committing it to your db.

Comment: I had thought of doing that as well. I actually started doing that for some phrase extraction on the same notes/data. I load it into a temporary table and remove a bunch of useless stuff to clean it up then I parse out word combinations to find phrases.

I like your idea of splitting at the datetime.

So, if I load the text/notes and an index number for the one to many relationship into another table and want to split at the datetime, what would that code look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to split the strings in code you'll need to start by putting together a regex.  I would match on the substring ":.. AM" or ":.. PM".  Matching on just a ":" seems a little dangerous given that this is a note field and users can probably type just about anything they want.

Please note this is untested, but the logic should be sound.  You may need to tinker with the match object accessors, and test that the index value is splitting exactly where you want, etc etc.

Start by reading your field into a string.  Then utilize regex to find the messages within the string.  Something like the following.

```
string pattern = @":.?*M";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
```

The match objects in the matches collection contain an index for the starting point where the match was found.  You'll want to loop through them and extract the substrings into individual strings.  Something like:

```
List<string> allNotes = new List<string>();    

for(i = 0, i < matches.Count, i++)
{
    string nextNote = string.Empty;
    int currentIndex = matches[i].index - 2;
    int endIndex = -1;
    if(matches[i+1] != null)
    { 
        endIndex = matches[i + 1].index - 2;
    }

    if(endIndex != -1)
    {
        nextNote = substring(currentIndex, (endIndex - currentIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        nextNote = substring(currentIndex);
    }

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextNote))
    {
        allNotes.Add(nextNote);
    }
}
```

These substrings should span the beginning of the timestamp through the character before the next time stamp.

You can then do another function to de-dupe the list.  Somethinglike:

```
Dictionary <string, string> dedupedDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(string note in allNotes)
{
    string noteHash = string.concat(note.substring(0, 6), note.substring(note.length - 7));

    if(!dedupedDict.Keys.Contains(noteHash))
    {   
        dedupedDict.Add(noteHash, note);
    }
}

return dedupedDict.Values().ToList();
```

You might need to include some checking for strings being the minimum length to avoid index out of bounds exceptions, and/or change the hash size(my example should be the first and last 6 characters).  You may also want to Trim() and/or Replace(".", "") on the punctuation at some point if you think it will help your matching.

Then use the list of deduped notes to populate your new CallNotes table.  You'll need your call Id as well.

Once you've cleaned up your current values, you can use the same methods to intercept new notes before they are put into your database.